# What is basis of tangent space of $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ if $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ is viewed as a manifold?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am jumbled up with new concepts and I need a help.

First, given a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ and a point $p \in M$, a tangent vector $v \in T_pM$ can be identified as: $\sum v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p = \varphi_*^{-1}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{\varphi(p)})$ for chart $(U, \varphi)$ about $p$.

Let $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be the space of $n \times n$ matrices with real entries. Then, $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ has basis $\{A_{ij}\}_{ij}$, where $A_{ij}$ has entries $a_{ij} = 1$ and all other entries $0$. Also there exists a (smooth?) mapping $\varphi: \mathbb R^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n^2}$, where $p = \sum (a_{ij} A_{ij}) \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} \mapsto \varphi(p) = (a_{11}, \cdots, a_{nn})) \in \mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Take any $p \in GL(n, \mathbb R)$. Since $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, $T_p GL(n, \mathbb R) \cong T_0 \mathbb R^{n^2}$. However, how do I characterize a basis of $T_p GL(n, \mathbb R)$? I was initially thinking of taking $\varphi^{-1}_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}|_{\varphi(p)})$ for $ij = 1, \cdots, n^2$, but it left me wondering what would the coordinate chart be in this case. I reached to a conclusion that this approach would not work since $x^{ij}$ would be equivalent to $A_{ij}$, and $A_{ij} \not\in GL(n, \mathbb R)$.

I would really appreciate if someone can clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting mixed up with equating canonical isomorphisms with actual equality! It takes some time to get used to.

> I reached a conclusion that this approach would not work since $x^{ij}$ would be equivalent to $A_{ij}$, and $A_{ij} \notin GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

This is actually not an issue at all! Let's consider a similar situation. Suppose you have the open unit disk $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, the tangent space to any point is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, even though these tangent vectors don't lie in $U$. The tangent vectors and position vectors lie in different spaces. It is true that you have a canonical isomorphism between them, but don't let that confuse you too much!

As for the coordinate chart, you have already provided it! The map $GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ you describe, essentially flattening the matrix, is a chart around any point, if you restrict it to a small enough open set. Note that around any invertible matrix, you have a neighbourhood where you are invertible (because the determinant is a continuous function) so this truly provides a local homeomorphism. In $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, the tangent vector basis is precisely $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ so pulling it back gives you the $A_{ij}$ as you mention. You were on the right path all along :)

In general, any open subset $U$ of a manifold $M$ is a manifold itself, and the tangent space $T_p(U) \cong T_p(M)$ canonically for $p \in U$.